# Wordpress 3.0 documentation

Tags: documentation, wordpress

quick question here.

Is there any Wordpress 3.0 documentation available? Some kind of list with all the new functions and variables?
All I can find are blog posts talking about the new features coming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress 3.0 Codex is probably a good place to start:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.0

Another good info source is the WordPress trac page (seeing what folks are working is a good clue to what's coming in Ver 3.0):

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/milestone/3.0

Comment: Thanks Harmen and Parvenu74 :)

Answer (score 0):

The [change log](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions) for version 3.0 isn't available, but there is this [Wordpress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/milestone/3.0) website where you can find all the milestones